# Random Text Strings Appearing Above Page Content When Using Repeater Control

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, repeater

I am having an issue with page rendering. I am developing in C# .NET 4.5, using Visual Studio 2015 as my development environment. When I debug the site locally, using Visual Studio, all the pages load and render perfectly, however, when I deploy it to our Test site, several pages that have `<asp:Repeater>` tags render with a random string of characters at the top of the page above the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag.

Here is an example of a page with no Repeater element:
[image: Page with no random string at top]

And the generated source code:
[image: Source code with no random string at top]

Here is an example of a page with a Repeater element, and the random string at the top. You can see that it's moved the page's background down a whole line as well:
[image: Page with random string at top]

And the generated source code for that:
[image: Source code with random string at top]

This is the top bit of code from my site's MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteMaster.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster.Web.masterpages.SiteMaster" ClientIDMode="Static" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
```

As you can see, there is no tag between the `<%@ Master %>` directive and the `<!DOCTYPE>` tag, so I am at a loss as to how text is getting inserted in between them. And also why it's not happening when debugging locally.

Any help would be much appreciated. Apologies for the blocking out of content, it's a Gov't website, so I can only share so much, unfortunately.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have `Response.Write` somewhere in a forgotten piece of code? Maybe that was meant for debugging and forgotten to be removed.

Comment: Yeah, I searched for those, and couldn't find them anywhere. Plus, if they were there, I would expect the text to be printed out when debugging locally as well.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was the IIS Application Pool. This site was being transitioned from Classic ASP to .NET, and the application pool assigned to it was still set to Classic mode. After changing it to Integrated mode, the random text strings went away. Still, pretty unexpected.